# Pedagogical projects in QFT for self-study purposes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I'm reading Srednicki's QFT textbook.  I'd like to do some projects that put the content learned into actual use.  Is there any good project topic?  I don't mind if it's already worked out some where.  I just want to experience the process of actually putting QFT into use, or simply relating the textbook knowledge to more problem-oriented situation.   The textbook problems are smaller drills.

Comment: I haven't used Srednicki, but I know Peskin and Schroeder contain a major proejct for every 'part' of the book.